# Shell Script : Grep usage

Tags: shell, grep, ps

I'm trying to kill a background process 'sleep 600'. For that I got the following script which is working fine.

```
ps -ef | grep "sleep 600" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} kill {}
```

I would like to know what does 'grep -v grep' do?

Comment: `grep -v pattern` removes all lines that match the pattern.  `grep -v grep` removes the `grep "sleep 600"` from the ps output.

Comment: Note that this particular pipeline is usually considered bad practice, as there are much better ways to do this task.  (`pgrep`, `pkill`, using patterns like `grep '[s]leep'`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please go through following.

```
ps -ef |                   ##Running ps -ef command to get all running pids information on server, passing its Output to next command as an Input.
grep "sleep 600" |         ##Looking for lines which have sleep 600 in it and sending its output as input to next line.
grep -v grep |             ##grep -v basically omits lines which have string grep in them, since grep command also creates a process to get string in above command so basically it is there to avoid that command's pid.
awk '{print $2}' |         ##Getting 2nd field of the process and sending it to next command as an Input.
xargs -I{} kill {}         ##Killing pid which was passed from previous command to this one.
```

***From `man grep`:***

> -v, --invert-match
>        Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

***Suggestion for OP's command improvement:*** You could remove multiple usage of `grep` and `awk` and could do this in a single `awk` like:

```
ps -ef | awk '/sleep 600/ && !/awk/{print $2}' | xargs -I{} kill {}
```

***OR make use of `pkill` option:*** Please make sure you test it before running in PROD/LIVE environments. Also while providing patterns make sure you are giving correct pattern which catches right process else it may kill other PIDs too, so just a fair warning here.

```
pkill -f 'sleep 60'
```

Comment: Very well explained answer

Answer (score 0):

Your command can be divided into several parts.

1. ps -ef | grep "sleep 600"

This will try to find sleep in running process list. But the problem is, grep will catch the grep itself.

```
# ps -ef | grep "sleep 600"
fahad     2327 13054  0 12:52 pts/9    00:00:00 sleep 600
root      2463 21217  0 12:52 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep 600
```

We do not need "grep --color=auto sleep 600" as it was just that command itself. So to exclude that, we can use `grep -v`

```
grep -v: "-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines"
```

So, after `grep -v` with a word or something will exclude that match. So here you are just picking the real `sleep 600` process.

Read more for grep from:

```
grep --help
```

Thank you.